# Testing generator output

Tags: generator, testing

I'm having trouble getting a 6kw generator to power a sub panel that was installed by a licensed electrician.  I would like to be able to test the generator's output.  How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to test that it simply works within reasonable parameters or that it can deliver up to the full 6kw of power? Do you want to test just voltage and current? Or also frequency and waveform? The more parameters to check the more equipment needed.

Comment: Some details on the trouble you're having might help

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late responding but a 100 watt light is just that, 100 watts so you can plug in 60 100 watt light bulbs or try a combination of easier things like a 1500 watt hair dryer and a 1500 watt toaster over etc.  Thinks that have heating elemets are the biggest and most accurate.

Comment: Four 120V 1500w heating elements mounted in a tank of water would give you the best resistive load. At $8 per it's a full 6kW load and can be series/parallel for testing 120V or 240V.